What do scriptures say about protecting weaker animals from predators?
Is there merits in say protecting a deer, antelope etc from tigers, lions etc? As per Manusmriti 1.90 it is duty of Vaishyas to protect animals

पशूनां रक्षणं दानमिज्याऽध्ययनमेव च । वणिक्पथं कुसीदं च वैश्यस्य कृषिमेव च ॥ ॥ १.९०॥

But isn't that disturbing natural order of things. A wild animal feasts upon other less powerful animals. Animals lack consciousness. So it can't be the case that wild animal is commiting a sin for feasting upon other animals.
So what should a human do in such a case? Should it intervene or let nature play it's course

This doesn't appears to be a question at all. पशूनां रक्षणं mentioned here doesn't means PETA level of activism. It refers to animal husbandry. And under natural circumstances, predatory animals don't require human protection.

Hows this not a question? Who is talking about protecting predatory animals? I am asking about protecting other animals from predatory animals

your logic is wrong. All living things have consciousness, it is just not at the same level of consciousness as a jiva manifests during human birth; but all living things have a jiva. As far as actions go, animals do not accumulate karma, a jiva accumulates good and bad karma only in the human birth.

Any interference or non-interference on your part can only gives you good or bad karma; none to the animal. It is a matter of individual circumstance whether you should interfere or not. Remember also that the protection of humans always far outweighs protection of animals - or plants.

Yes. Animals' consciousness falls short to that of humans. And yes, I do know animals don't accrue karma. However this has nothing to do with my question.
